# ReSharper - how to disable generation of rubbish documentation headers in Code Cleanup

Tags: resharper, stylecop, resharper-6.0, code-documentation

We're using ReSharper 6.0 with StyleCop for ReSharper.

Although we use the StyleCop rule that members must have documentation headers, we don't want ReSharper's code cleanup facility to generate documentation headers for us, because they're inevitably rubbish. Bad doc headers are worse than none at all because they're less likely to be updated than added in the first place.

We tried turning off the setting 'Insert text into documentation and file headers' in ReSharper => Options => Tools => StyleCop but it bloody resets itself when you restart visual studio.

Any ideas how we can stop Code Cleanup creating documentation headers for us?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ReSharper -> Options -> Tools section -> Code Cleanup -> select StyleCop profile -> Documentation section -> untick 1600.`

Will prevent default documentation headers being created but StyleCop will still enforce that they should be there.

Comment: For me, I had to set `1639: Update file header` to `Do not change`.

Comment: Also, if you are using a custom file header, and don't want to replace it with the standard StyleCop header, untick `1633-1641: Update file header` under StyleCop -> Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The second step, after blocking code generation is Removing the rubbish.
I used a regex Search/Replace through visual studio.

Regex is for header :

```
// ---.*\r\n\/\/.*\r\n\/\/.*\r\n\/\/.*\r\n\/\/.*\r\n\/\/.*\r\n.*\r\n\/\/.-{116}
```

Regex to remove Generated summaries

```
\s{4}\/\/\/\s<summary>(.*)\r\n.*\r\n.*</summary>
```

Caution : it will remove ALL summaries, even the good ones, so check the replacement scope before launching it. (git checkout might be your friend...)